# How to replace column values based on values in another column in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to develop my R skills after a few years working with Pandas, and have a problem that's got me stumped.

I've split a column of data in a dataframe called df that broadly takes the following form:

```
"MN - place1 - time"
...
"ST - place2 - time"
```

I've used the separate function to split the data into three columns and aimed to isolate the middle column as the updated column:

```
cleaning_df <- separate(data = data, col = location, into = c("type", 'location', "time_data"), sep = "-")
```

It takes the form:

```
type    location    time_data
MN      place1     time
ST      place2      time
```

Unfortunately, there are typos which mean that hyphens aren't used to separate the first two fields.

For instance:

```
"STPlace2 - time"
```

Which separate can't handle - or I couldn't work out how.

Luckily, there aren't too many mistakes so I'd created a simple lookup table, location_lookup, which I was hoping to use as a dataframe to correct the data.

It's of the form:

```
Broken_type     Correct_middle
STPlace2        Place2
...             ...
```

With Pandas, I could write a straightforward, if un-pythonic and un-Pandas, apply function to go line-by-line through the newly-generated 'type' and 'place' columns.

It would then update values in 'place' where the value in 'type' matched in the look-up.

Is there a neater way of doing this? I've not been able to work through a solution using joins which would clearly be more efficient.

UPDATE:

The output from the separate function from my example, along with the error would be:

```
type     place     time
MN       place1    time
ST       place2    time
STPlace2 time      NA
```

I want to be able to create a function or join to use the look-up table

```
Broken_type     Correct_middle
STPlace2        Place2
...             ...
```

to identify that the third row in the above left column is wrong, and replace the value 'time' with 'Place2.

The eventual output column would then be:

```
place
place1
place2
Place2
```

Comment: If there are no patterns available, then it is difficult for to split up.

Comment: You're right, so I've created a dataframe to manually provide a lookup to correct them. Luckily, there aren't that many errors, but they are repeated hundreds of times. What I can't work out is how to 'find and replace' the wrong values in the column with correct values.

Comment: Ca you please provide a small reproducible example as it becomes easier for others to test

Comment: Is the first column always capitalised or it always 2 characters in length? Does Place always have the first letter capitalised?  Or are these patterns unavailable because of the aforementioned spelling mistakes?

Comment: @MorganBall - you're right. It should have a two or three-character code that is upper case. However, data has been manually entered in wrongly once so the field doesn't exist. It has then been repeated multiple times.

Comment: Based on the example you showed, I posted a solution.  If the patterns are varying and not all are showed, it won't work

Comment: You can first test the third column for NAs so you know where you have a problem. You could then test whether the first two characters are capitalised or not. If they are not you know the first field is missing. If they are capitalised you need to somehow test the 3rd/4th character to determine where the separation occurs. Are there a limited number of places that can be input (i.e. could you reference a substring from the broken row against the places identified in the non broken rows to see if the place exists?)

Answer (score 0):

We can pass `regex` on `extract`

```
extract(data, location, into = c("type", "location", "time_data"),
           "(.{2})[^[:alnum:]]*([[:alnum:]]+)\\s+-\\s+(.*)")
#   type location time_data
#1   MN   place1      time
#2   ST   place2      time
#3   ST   Place2      time
```

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(location = c("MN - place1 - time", "ST - place2 - time", 
"STPlace2 - time")), .Names = "location", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: That's an elegant solution for this case. The reason I've tried to use a look-up table is that there are fewer than 10 types of error, but going forward it would be easier to highlight new errors, rather than trying to maintain a regex.

Comment: @elksie5000  As I mentioned in the comments, this works only for specific cases you showed in the example

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly elegant, but...

```
df$location <- sapply(1:length(df$type), function(x){
  if (df$type[x] %in% location_lookup$Broken_type){
    location_lookup$Correct_middle[match(df$type[x], location_lookup$Broken_type)]
  } else {

    df$place[x]
  }

})
```